# Koush Ion onCompleted callback - handle CancellationException

Tags: java, android, exception, asynccallback, ion-koush

I am following an example of the popular Ion library that Koush created: [Download a File with a progress bar](https://github.com/koush/ion#download-a-file-with-a-progress-bar) and I can see from [one of his samples](https://github.com/koush/ion/blob/master/ion-sample/src/com/koushikdutta/ion/sample/ProgressBarDownload.java#L72) that it is possible to send a cancellation using `downloading.cancel()`.

*NB: `downloading` was declared as `Future<File>`.*

When the `cancel()` method is called it throws a `CancellationException`.  I would like to handle this exception specifically, instead of catching it generally.

My first thought is to wrap a try / catch block, and use something like:

```
try { 
    //...
} catch (CancellationException ce) {
    //...
}
```

However if you look at [his example](https://github.com/koush/ion#download-a-file-with-a-progress-bar), you will see that the onCompleted callback uses 2 inputs: `Exception e` and `File result`.

The sample [here (line 72)](https://github.com/koush/ion/blob/master/ion-sample/src/com/koushikdutta/ion/sample/ProgressBarDownload.java#L72) shows this:

```
if (e != null) {
    Toast.makeText(ProgressBarDownload.this, "Error downloading file", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    return;
}
```

This appears to be an alternative to a try / catch block which is generalising an error if an exception exists.  However my aim to return a different toast message if the `CancellationException` was caught.

Comment: you have to write custom exception .

Answer (score 1):

To handle exceptions individually we can look for the exception type in the  instance of the thrown exception `e`.

This is the solution that works for me:

```
if (e instanceof CancellationException) {
  //CancellationException was found
}
```